# How can I run this VBS script from a shared network drive, from command line on multiple computers?

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd, shared, drive

I created a VBS script and put it on a shared drive IT uses in my office, what I want is to be able to use it with another computer via command line WITHOUT writing the entire path because it's very long, and defeats the purpose of the script.
The script is this:

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd.exe /c net stop AeXAgentSrvHost", 1, true
oShell.run "cmd.exe /c net stop ""Altiris Deployment Agent""", 1, true
oShell.run "cmd.exe /c net start AeXAgentSrvHost", 1, true
oShell.run "cmd.exe /c net start ""Altiris Deployment Agent""", 1, true
Set oShell = Nothing'
```

Comment: I'm confused. Do you mean you want to create a shortcut to this script?

Comment: No, I want to execute it from my pc via cmd to run it on another computer

Comment: You want to spawn a process on a remote computer?

Comment: Let's put it this way, My computer is A, another computer in the same network is B. So, I want to execute the script on B FROM A like: //hostname run script.vbs, or something like that

Comment: OK. And what about the command line part? You want to _use_ the command line to spawn it or you want a command window to appear on the remote user's PC? Also, what do you mean by _"without writing the entire path because it's very long"_.

Comment: First one, I want to spawn it. The path to the script is like: \\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder, 6 folders to get to the script, is there anyway to not type it? and instead just type script.vbs or something like that?

Comment: Couple things: 1) Assuming you have the authority, you could use WMI to stop/start services on remote machines without spawning the script on them. That would, arguably, be the easier route. 2) You could create a shortcut to your script (or to the folder that contains your script). I guess I don't understand why you need to launch it via the command line. You can still run _command-line scripts_ via a shortcut.

Comment: 1) Don´t know what WMI is. 2) That way I would need to create the shortcut on every computer beforehand, so no. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using the [`Win32_Service`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418(v=vs.85).aspx) class within a VBScript to stop a service on a remote computer. There's no need to spawn a script on the remote PC (unless you *really* want to).

```
Const COMPUTER_NAME = "johndoe1"
Const SERVICE_NAME  = "AeXAgentSrvHost"

Dim objWMI
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & COMPUTER_NAME & "\root\cimv2")

With objWMI.Get("Win32_Service.Name='" & SERVICE_NAME & "'")
    If .Started Then .StopService
End With
```

See the link above for a complete list of properties and methods for the `Win32_Service` class.

If you need to run this for many computers, you have a number of options:

- Use a hard-coded array of computer names
- Read a list from a text file, database, or other form of storage
- Prompt for computer names using an `InputBox()` or read from `StdIn`
- Pass one or more names as command-line parameters
- Etc.

There should be plenty of examples for each method on this site.